# error lnk2019 unresolved symbol sqlite3_open when i compile my MFC application in x64bit mode and no issue in win32 mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, mfc

error lnk2019 unresolved symbol sqlite3_open when i compile my MFC application in x64bit mode and no issue in win32 mode. please help me

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Is sqlite3_open in a `.dll` or `.lib` ?

Comment: due to my company's policy I can not share my code, but I repeat there is no problem when compile in win32 mode, issue is with x64 bit mode compilation, is it because I use sqlite3 lib for 32bit? where can I get sqlite3 library for x64 bit ?

Comment: I link in SQLite3.lib in  additional dependencies in VS2010 but sqlite.dll file is also there and .dll is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pretty much answered the question yourself. You are using a 32bit `.dll` and/or `.lib` to compile 64bit code.

Change to 64bit and you should be fine.
As for sqlite3, there is currently no 64bit available on their official website.

Comment: I used this link for sqlite3.dll for x64 bit as mentioned in link but did not worked

Comment: What did not work, any errors ? # I'm not testing everything I get from google results. Obviously. You could have looked this up in less than 30 seconds yourself. #

Comment: same error which I mentioned in very first question and the given link only contains sqlite3-64.dll and does not contain  sqlite3.lib file

Comment: should I build sqlite3 library for x64 bit by myself?

Comment: As you can see from their website, there is no official 64bit version out. You either search for a 64bit `.lib` & `.dll` or compile it yourself.